# Pandas: groupby and transform with datetime

Tags: datetime, pandas, group-by, transform

I am still a beginner with pandas and stumbled across a very weird behaviour when I use a groupby-transform operation on multiple columns including a column of dtype datetime64[ns].

My (toy)example is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.datetime(2014,3,17),    pd.datetime(2014,3,24), pd.datetime(2014,3,17)], 'hdg_id': [4041,4041,4041],'stock': [1.0,1.0,1.0]})

In[117]: df
Out[117]: 
    date  hdg_id  stock
0 2014-03-17    4041      1
1 2014-03-24    4041      1
2 2014-03-17    4041      1
```

I now groupby date and hdg_id (for hdg_id it is trivial, since there is only one unique value, but I need the multiple grouping to produce the result, my actual applications are more complicated of course):

```
In[118]: df.groupby(['date', 'hdg_id']).transform(sum)
Out[118]: 
           stock
0   0.000000e+00
1  4.940656e-324
2   0.000000e+00
```

This is not my expected result. If I convert the column date to type string I get what I expect:

```
In[129]: df['date']=df['date'].astype(str)
In[131]: df.groupby(['date', 'hdg_id']).transform(sum)
Out[131]: 
   stock
0      2
1      1
2      2
```

Can anybody share some insides what is happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this looks like a bug to me, if the columns that are grouped on are not datetime then it works as expected, similarly if you set the index by those columns then it works as expected

Comment: Appears to be a known bug and will be fixed in next version:  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10124

Comment: @John and Ed: Thanks a lot, this is, at least in some way,  helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use .transform(sum)?

You could do something like this:
df.groupby(['date', 'hdg_id']).sum()
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need the transform because I need to preserve the original dataframe for further processing.